# scrapy отфильтровать запросы в middleware по callback

Tags: python, scrapy

запросы создаются линкэкстрактором с колбеком parse_item, вот его мне и нужно  ловить. но он всегда _response_downloaded

```
def process_response(self,request, response, spider):
  print request.callback.__str__()
 #выводит всегда _response_downloaded
```

## решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37737936/6423387